# latex multirow figures with side caption

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats

I need to create figures and caption as follows.

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that by the »[subcaption](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)« package from the »[caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)« bundle.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{First}
      \label{subfig-1:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{Second}
      \label{subfig-2:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{Third}
      \label{subfig-3:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
      \caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
      \label{fig:dummy}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{Fourth}
      \label{subfig-4:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{Fifth}
      \label{subfig-5:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The image files are available with the »[mwe](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe)« package installed on your system.

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am getting an error 'missing number treated as zero'. what should I do?

Comment: @user570593: Make sure that you have the latest version of the involved packages. Use the package manager of your TeX distribution to do an update if necessary.